# Get MIN value between 3 columns on same row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Though I have come up with a couple of working solutions to what I am looking for, I am wondering if there is a more streamlined way of determining which of 3 columns from a single row contains the smallest/min value. Below is an example of the data I am working with:

| AccountNumber | Job | DaysSinceLastSale | DaysSinceLastCharge | DaysSinceEstablished |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| YO502 | NULL | NULL | 5283 | NULL |
| YO525 | NULL | 2303 | 2303 | 5917 |
| ZE100 | 1 | 190 | 449 | 707 |
| ZE100 | 2 | 160 | 279 | 615 |
| ZI402 | NULL | 2109 | 2109 | NULL |

And what the outcome would be, which is just the new column of DaysInactive containing the lesser of the 3 non-null DaysSincexxx values:

| AccountNumber | Job | DaysSinceLastSale | DaysSinceLastCharge | DaysSinceEstablished | DaysInactive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| YO502 | NULL | NULL | 5283 | NULL | 5283 |
| YO525 | NULL | 2303 | 2303 | 5917 | 2303 |
| ZE100 | 1 | 190 | 449 | 707 | 190 |
| ZE100 | 2 | 160 | 279 | 615 | 160 |
| ZI402 | NULL | 2109 | 2109 | NULL | 2109 |

This is what I have to this point that simply uses a series of CASE expressions to compare them with. The objective is to find the lowest value of days of inactivity for a client job based on any of 3 different date values tied to the job. And to be clear, 2 of the columns (DaysSinceLastSale and DaysSinceLastCharge) are the primary target, with the 3rd (DaysSinceEstablished) being a last resort in the event the first 2 are NULL (All 3 of them can actually be NULL, in which case we default to 99999). I am ultimately using this in a PowerBI report so a >= slicer can be setup for the end-users to manually enter the minimum number of inactive days a record should have in order to be returned on the report visual:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN COALESCE(DaysSinceLastSale, DaysSinceLastCharge) IS NOT NULL THEN 
            CASE WHEN COALESCE(DaysSinceLastSale, DaysSinceLastCharge) <= COALESCE(DaysSinceLastCharge, DaysSinceLastSale)  
                THEN COALESCE(DaysSinceLastSale, DaysSinceLastCharge) 
                ELSE COALESCE(DaysSinceLastCharge, DaysSinceLastSale) 
            END
        ELSE  COALESCE(DaysSinceEstablished, 99999) 
        END as DaysInactive
    , DS.*  
FROM #DS2 DS
```

This was my original solution but I just didn't like having all the sub-queries and UNIONs:

```
SELECT 
    NormalizedDaysInactive.DaysInactive
    , DS.* 
FROM #DS2 DS 
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        AccountNumber, BillingLevel, Job, MIN(ISNULL(DaysInactive, 99999)) as DaysInactive 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT AccountNumber, BillingLevel, Job, MIN(DaysSinceLastSale) as DaysInactive FROM #DS2 GROUP BY AccountNumber, BillingLevel, Job
        UNION ALL
        SELECT AccountNumber, BillingLevel, Job, MIN(DaysSinceLastCharge) as DaysInactive FROM #DS2 GROUP BY AccountNumber, BillingLevel, Job
        UNION ALL
        SELECT AccountNumber, BillingLevel, Job, MIN(DaysSinceEstablished) as DaysInactive FROM #DS2 GROUP BY AccountNumber, BillingLevel, Job
    ) ActDays
    GROUP BY AccountNumber, BillingLevel, Job
    HAVING MIN(ISNULL(DaysInactive, 1)) > 0
) NormalizedDaysInactive ON NormalizedDaysInactive.AccountNumber = DS.AccountNumber
    AND (NormalizedDaysInactive.Job = DS.Job OR NormalizedDaysInactive.BillingLevel = 'Account')
```

Appreciate any suggestions! Thanks

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: Sample data and desired results will help (although not as [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use APPLY to do a little "inline" unpivot operation and then grab the min value. I added the column `TypeOfActivity` as well as it might come in handy to know what activity as well

### Min Value Between Multiple Columns

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable AS A
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP(1) *
    FROM (
        VALUES 
            ('Sale',DaysSinceLastSale)
            ,('Charge',DaysSinceLastCharge)
            ,('Established',DaysSinceEstablished)
    ) AS DTA(TypeOfActivity,DaysSinceActivity)
    WHERE DaysSinceActivity IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY DaysSinceActivity
) AS B
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it's pretty close...just needed to adjust for NULL values in the CROSS APPLY > VALUES and it worked great. I was considering using VALUES as the source, in some way, but I've not much experience using that feature so wasn't real sure on how to put it together.

Comment: Ah, sorry just wrote the code off the top of my head. Just needed a WHERE clause and it should ignore NULL values. See my edit

Comment: Actually I adjusted mine to use COALESCE on each of the three VALUES, setting the null replacement to 99999, because ultimately we always want some kind of value to return even if they are all NULL.  So instead of just ('Sale', DaysSinceLastSale)  I used ('Sale', COALESCE(DaysSinceLastSale,99999)). In any event, I really like this approach and I can see a lot of benefit to using this in the future.

Comment: @svenGUTT You could use `Coalesce` on the value in the _select list_, i.e. `select A.*, Coalesce( DTA.DaysSinceActivity, 99999 ) as DaysSinceActivity from ... ;`, rather than on each value in the `Values` clause.